# Product Picture not show i

Tags: php, mysql

This code is use add and update product but image not showing. i think its paths error but I cant resolve it.kindly find error in this code where I mistake.Product images not showing on the product page .
i follow A series I write a same code but not working but in tutorial working fine .Tankx in advance

*Product.Php*

```
<?php
require('top.inc.php');

if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']!=''){
    $type=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['type']);
    if($type=='status'){
        $operation=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['operation']);
        $id=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['id']);
        if($operation=='active'){
            $status='1';
        }else{
            $status='0';
        }
        $update_status_sql="update product set status='$status' where id='$id'";
        mysqli_query($con,$update_status_sql);
    }
    
    if($type=='delete'){
        $id=get_safe_value($con,$_GET['id']);
        $delete_sql="delete from product where id='$id'";
        mysqli_query($con,$delete_sql);
    }
}

$sql="select product.*,categories.categories from product,categories where product.categories_id=categories.id order by product.id desc";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
<div class="content pb-0">
    <div class="orders">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-12">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h4 class="box-title">Products </h4>
                   <h4 class="box-link"><a href="manage_product.php">Add Product</a> </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body--">
                   <div class="table-stats order-table ov-h">
                      <table class="table ">
                         <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th class="serial">#</th>
                               <th>ID</th>
                               <th>Categories</th>
                               <th>Name</th>
                               <th>Image</th>
                               <th>MRP</th>
                               <th>Price</th>
                               <th>Qty</th>
                               <th></th>
                            </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                            <?php 
                            $i=1;
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){?>
                            <tr>
                               <td class="serial"><?php echo $i?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row['categories']?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                               <td><img src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH.$row['image']?>"/></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row['mrp']?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row['price']?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row['qty']?></td>
                               <td>
                                <?php
                                if($row['status']==1){
                                    echo "<span class='badge badge-complete'><a href='?type=status&operation=deactive&id=".$row['id']."'>Active</a></span>&nbsp;";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<span class='badge badge-pending'><a href='?type=status&operation=active&id=".$row['id']."'>Deactive</a></span>&nbsp;";
                                }
                                echo "<span class='badge badge-edit'><a href='manage_product.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></span>&nbsp;";
                                
                                echo "<span class='badge badge-delete'><a href='?type=delete&id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></span>";
                                
                                ?>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                         </tbody>
                      </table>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
require('footer.inc.php');
?>
```

When I upload pic this error show in console and pic not show on front end I try to solve couple of hours but I cant find error .i know I have little bit mistake but I cant find it.

```
GET http://localhost/AdminPanel/media/product/http://127.0.0.1/php/ecom/media/product/929442919_111.png 403 (Forbidden)
```

Comment: The error is right in front of you. Just look at the "GET" path in your errors and then you can kindly solve it

Answer (score 0):

GetSet is right. The error is pretty quick to spot in the `GET` statement and the problem comes from here:

```
PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH.$row['image']
```

I'm assuming that `PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH` = `http://localhost/AdminPanel/media/product/` so you'll probably need to clean the data in `$row['image']` to remove the unnecessary stuff.

***Important:** this is not a recommended solution, but it will get you closer to something a little more logical.*

Change:

```
PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH.$row['image']
```

To:

```
PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH . str_replace($row['image'], 'http://127.0.0.1/php/ecom/media/', '')
```

Ideally there would be a lot more data validation and whatnot going on before spitting this HTML out to a browser, but this should get you part of the way there.

Comment: The level of detail in your response explains why, too.

Comment: As a developer who has direct access to: the database, the web server, the file system, the code, it is *your* responsibility to perform the due diligence. Does the file exist? Can it be accessed via the web server? Is the URL the same as what is recorded in the database? Are there permission issues? Etc, etc, etc, etc.. Random people on the internet can offer basic suggestions and pointers, but it's *up to you* to understand the system your are building and make it work.